Variance for two Heads or Tails in a row i.e. $HH$ or $TT$
This is a question from Mark Joshi's book:

We play a game, with a fair coin. The game stops when either two heads (H) or tails (T) appear consecutively. What is the expected time until the game stops? What is the variance of $N$?

$N$ = number of tosses in a game with first occurrence of either $HH$ or $TT$
I attemped it using Markov Chains, got the following two equations:
\begin{align}
E_{0,2} &= 1 + 1\cdot E_{1,2} \\
E_{1,2} &= 1 + \frac{1}{2}E_{1,2} + \underbrace { \frac{1}{2}E_{2,2}}_{=0} 
\end{align}
Solving these equations, we get: $E_{0,2}=3$ i.e. $\mathbb{E}[N]=3$
Now, how to continue and find the variance $Var(N)$ from here?

Can you compute $\mathbb{E}[N^2]$?

If you haven't received the proper training for the problem, why are you attempting to tackle the problem?

@user2661923 That is definitely not the answer of the question. How about minding your business?

The standard technique of identifying an absorbing state in a Markov chain only yields the expectation of $N$.
For this simple example it is possible to write down the distribution of $N$. Note that the final outcomes HH and TT are perfectly symmetric since the coin is fair.
If $n\geq 2$ is odd then
$$\mathbb P(N=n) = 2P(X_1=H, X_2=T,X_3=H,X_4=T,\ldots ,X_{n-2}=H,X_{n-1}=T,X_n=T)=\frac 1{2^{n-1}},$$
and if $n\geq 2$ is even then
$$\mathbb P(N=n) = 2P(X_1=T, X_2=H,X_3=T,X_4=H,\ldots ,X_{n-2}=H,X_{n-1}=T,X_n=T)=\frac 1{2^{n-1}}.$$
Thus $$\forall n\geq 2, \quad  \mathbb P(N=n)=\frac 1{2^{n-1}}.$$
By differentiating the power series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty x^n = \frac{x^2}{1-x}$, one obtains $$\begin{align}
\mathbb E[N] &= \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac n{2^{n-1}} = 3
\\ \mathbb E[N^2] &= \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac {n^2}{2^{n-1}} = 11,
\end{align}
$$
thus $\mathbb V[N] = 2$.

Got it, thank you so much!

This makes sense but if we have the same question except 3H or 3T, then it seems that the probability distribution of $N$ when approaching this way remains the same (as the coins are unbiased), and the summation starts from $3$ for expectation and we get a smaller expected value. But the expected value for HHH or TTT is 7. Where is it going wrong?

@Sid For the HH/TT game, when you reach TT, the only two possible sequences of play from the beginning are HTHT...HTT and THTH...HTT. The other game HHH/TTT is not so easy, as there may be other more complex patterns before you reach TTT.

So, in that case, the best way would be to stick with standard technique using Markov Chains? Because there was another question that generalizes to $\underbrace{H\ldots H}{\text{n times}}$ or $\underbrace{T\ldots T}{\text{n times}}$ which can be easily solved using Markov Chains for the expected value, at least.

@Sid yes, to compute the expectation in the generalized game you can still use a Markov chain with an absorbing state and solve the system of equations.

You have a sequence of alternating results until the first non-alternation.
After the first flip, each try will either be different from its prior (a "failure") or repeat its prior (a "success") with identical probability.
$$(N-1)\sim\mathcal{Geo}_1(1/2)$$
So, you may find the expectation and variance of $N$ in terms of the expectation and variance of $N-1$.
